# How to convert file dates to a particular format when using 'ls'

Tags: files, ls, timestamps, coreutils

I have the following input data:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 abmnyu abmnyu 0 Dec 30 07:06 ffd_in_imp_bus.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 abmnyu abmnyu 0 Dec 30 07:06 ffd_ik_imp_bus.dat
```

I need `Dec 30` to be displayed in the format `20171230` while using `ls -l`, as shown below:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 abmnyu abmnyu 0 20171230 07:06 ffd_in_imp_bus.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 abmnyu abmnyu 0 20171230 07:06 ffd_ik_imp_bus.dat
```

Comment: I think ["julian date" refers to something different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using GNU `ls` (this is standard on Linux systems), it has a `--time-style` option which can be used to change the date/time format.

The built-in format closest to what you want is `long-iso`.

e.g.

```
$ ls -l --time-style=long-iso
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 2017-12-30 21:26 ffd_ik_imp_bus.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 2017-12-30 21:26 ffd_in_imp_bus.dat
```

You can also use a custom format using the same date formatting specification as in GNU `date`:

```
$ ls -l --time-style='+%Y%m%d %H:%M'
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 20171230 21:26 ffd_ik_imp_bus.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 20171230 21:26 ffd_in_imp_bus.dat
```

From `man ls`:

> **--time-style=STYLE**
>
> with `-l`, show times using style STYLE: `full-iso`, `long-iso`, `iso`, `locale`, or `+FORMAT`
>
> FORMAT is interpreted like  in `date'
>
> if FORMAT is `FORMAT1<newline>FORMAT2`, then FORMAT1 applies to non-recent files and FORMAT2 to recent files.
>
> if STYLE is prefixed with `posix-`, STYLE takes effect only outside the POSIX locale